# Recaptcha Styling Using Zend PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using Zend_Service_ReCaptcha in a project and wish to customize the colour scheme of the box, however I am completely stumped on which function to use to achieve this.
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardElements.html#zend.form.standardElements.captcha doesn't seem to shed any light.

Answers are appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Setting this options via form element params won't work! This options (“*theme*” and “*lang*”) should be passed to the service instead!

Here's *Zend_Service_ReCaptcha* constructor:

```
public function __construct($publicKey = null, $privateKey = null,
                                $params = null, $options = null, $ip = null)
{
…
```

Usage:

```
$options = array('theme' => 'white', 'lang' => 'ru');
$recaptcha = new Zend_Service_ReCaptcha($publicKey, $privateKey, null, $options);

$this->view->recaptcha = $recaptcha->getHtml();
```

Otherwise, if you wanna use form elements, you should get service object first. Try something like that:

```
$options = array('theme' => 'white', 'lang' => 'ru');
$form->getElement('captcha')->getCaptcha()->getService()->setOptions($options);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the theme option via the [captcha options](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardElements.html#zend.form.standardElements.captcha) to the form element:

Something like:

```
$element = new Zend_Form_Element_Captcha('foo', array(
    'label' => "Please verify you're a human",
    'captcha' => array(
        'captcha' => 'Recaptcha',
        'timeout' => 300,
        'theme'   => 'red'
    ),
));
```

Comment: Hi David the script is not complete in this way. You have to add the private and public key parameters. Regards

Answer (score 0):

You get the public and private keys when you register at http://recaptcha.net/ and set them in your form as follows  $recaptcha_service = new Zend_Service_ReCaptcha($public, $private);